# SQL Query Filter and SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to make a SQL query to do that:

1. SELECT TOP 6 Records from Table [Paiements_17_18].
2. Filter **ONLY** The 6 records by [Type_Reglements] = "Espèces".
3. Do a SUM of [Montant] field.

I Tried This but It's not working *(Where Condition)* :

```
    SELECT S1.TotalMontantESP, S2.TotalMontantCHQ, S3.TotalMontantLCN, S4.NombreFactures, S5.PremièreDate, S5.DernièreDate, S5.PremièreFacture, S5.DernièreFacture, S5.NumeroCaisse
FROM
    (SELECT sum(Montant) As TotalMontantESP FROM (SELECT TOP 6 Montant FROM Paiements_17_18) WHERE Type_Reglement = "Espèces") As P) As S1,
    (SELECT sum(Montant) As TotalMontantCHQ FROM (SELECT TOP 6 Montant FROM Paiements_17_18) WHERE Type_Reglement = "Chèque") As P) As S2,
    (SELECT sum(Montant) As TotalMontantLCN FROM (SELECT TOP 6 Montant FROM Paiements_17_18) WHERE Type_Reglement = "LCN") As P) As S3,
    (SELECT Count(N_Facture) AS NombreFactures FROM (SELECT DISTINCT N_Facture FROM (SELECT TOP 6 N_Facture FROM Paiements_17_18) AS P1) AS P2) AS S4,
    (SELECT Min([Date_Reglement]) AS PremièreDate, Max([Date_Reglement]) AS DernièreDate, Min([N_Facture]) AS PremièreFacture, Max([N_Facture]) AS DernièreFacture, Max([N_Caisse]) AS NumeroCaisse 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 6 Paiements_17_18.* FROM Paiements_17_18) AS P3) AS S5;
```

Comment: Ah! The lovely and very helpful: *It's not working* /s. Please post errors/undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT sum(Montant)
FROM (SELECT TOP 6 p.*
      FROM Paiements_17_18 as p
      ORDER BY ID_Paiement DESC
     ) as p
WHERE T.Type_Reglement = "Espèces";
```

It is a little hard to follow the logic of your query, but I'm pretty sure you are doing the `where` *after* taking the `sum()`.

Comment: I put the whole code so that you can understand my logic.